# tensorflow - Import Error : cannot import name rnn_cell_impl

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

Using anaconda, I had installed python 2.7 and tensorflow 1.0.0 to run the package called `DeepNovo`.

Then I got following error when I tried to run this python script:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "deepnovo_main.py", line 15, in module import deepnovo_model
File "/Data2/HJE/DeepNovo/deepnovo_model.py", line 43, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.ops import rnn_cell_impl 
ImportError: cannot import name rnn_cell_impl
```

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You want to include a package. That package already required other package. package name is `rnn_cell_impl`. Make sure path is correct. You can read [python modules packages](https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/)